# How to manipulate CSHTML with Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, razor, roslyn

I'm trying to use Roslyn to do some mass refactoring on my code.

The idea is to remove a specific using and insert them directly in the code.

For example

```cs
using My.Awesome.Namespace;
...
var temp = MyType.Prop;
```

would become

```cs
var temp = My.Awesome.Namespace.MyType.Prop;
```

I already have a working solution for .cs files using `MSBuildWorkspace` to parse my solution, find the using reference and replace them in the file. But I can't find how to do the same on the cshtml files.

They do not appear in the `Documents` property of my project.

Any idea?

Here is the code I'm using to parse the solution

```cs
public void Process(string solutionPath, string projectName, string baseNamespace)
{
    //Force import csharp projects
    MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
    var _ = typeof(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Formatting.CSharpFormattingOption
    using (var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
    {
        var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;

        var project = solution.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == projectName)
        if (project == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        foreach (var document in project.Documents)
        {
            if (document.SourceCodeKind != SourceCodeKind.Regular)
                continue;

            Console.WriteLine("Fixing file " + document.Name);

            // Remove using of baseNamespace from doc
            var newDoc = RemoveUsing(document, baseNamespace);
            solution = solution.WithDocumentSyntaxRoot(document.Id, newDoc);
        }
        msWorkspace.TryApplyChanges(solution);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm just curious: what prompted you to remove the `usings` at the top and insert the namespaces everywhere?  Is it a style choice?  I'm not offering any argument, just curious.

Comment: We are migrating from resources to po to do the translation of our app.
All our resources are in a "Project.Translations" folder.

Most of the time we use the complete path with the namespace to reference a resource in our code.

But sometimes we did made a using with Project.Translations.

So as a first step I just want to replace them all with the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decent solution for scanning, parsing, compiling, and getting the semantic models for a solution's .cshtml files: [Getting a SemanticModel of a cshtml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392086/getting-a-semanticmodel-of-a-cshtml-file)